# Best practice in CakePHP for call function in another controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an controller attachment responsible for handling all uploads files. This controller uses a component to perform this control.

Now I have the following problem, I need call a function implemented in attachments controller from another controller, what is the best practice in this case? whereas:

- It is not advised to call a function from a controller to another.
- If I implement the function in my model this would have to use a component that is also not advised.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. It's completely wrong and violating the MVC pattern.

Files represent a single entity in the system and should be handled as those (IMO) and in the model layer, not in the controller. You implement the validation and saving logic in a *single* model and access that model through associations from other places if you have too.

For example User hasOne Avatar, Gallery hasMany Image. Where the Avatar and Gallery association is your attachments or files table model.

I've written a plugin that does exactly the above and a little more
https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage

Use that or move your controller logic into a model. Controllers should be really really skinny and only have, well, controlling logic, they should never care about data handling or manipulation.